# ios custom progress bar designing

Tags: ios, progress-bar

I want to create a custom progress bar for my app. I am new to iOS development and finding it difficult to understand codes on google which confuse me a lot. What I want is like growing animated progress bar. 
e.g: like showing progress in terms of a tree growth from small plant(to a complete tree) which denotes the process completion.

Where and how to start? And also is Core Graphics or cocos2d which one will be apt for this?

Comment: Rather than trying to find code on Google, how about writing some?. If you are new to iOS development it's hard to know where to start helping you. You haven't said what you've tried or what you are having difficulty with. Try reading the [iOS Drawing and Printing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) to start with and then ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 5):

If you're doing something graphical like a tree growing, do you already have the animation you want to use as a series of images?

If so, you could use a `UIImageView`. Whenever you want to update your progress bar, just check the progress of your task, and use that to work out which number image to display. So if you had twelve images, you could find the percentage complete of your task, divide by 100 then multiply by twelve (and then convert to an `int`) to get the image number you want.

Once you've done that, just get the appropriately named image and put it in your image view:

```
self.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"frame-%i", myImageNumber]];
```

As for when to do the progress check, that depends on the task you are doing. Some tasks have a natural place to inject a callback to update the UI, and for others it's better to just use a timer.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot change much in uiprogressbar instead you can use UISlide to behave like progressbar
.

you can only change the frame of progressbar as:-

```
UIProgressView *progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle
:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
[progressView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,10)];
```

you can create a uiSlider and make its ThumbImage to nil,setMinimumTrackImage ans maxtrackImage and then use the custom function on it to show the progress

[custom UISlider](http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=250)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD
Try this code its modst widely used open source code for your kind of purpose

Comment: thats more like activityindicator

Comment: Yeah there are options to choose between.

Comment: go with this open source code. it is really helpful and will solve ur query.

Comment: ya..  Danyal Aytekin is right... i want it like a tree growing.. and not normal progress bars